# Correctly set dual (mixed) authorization configuration on .net core

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, cookies, jwt

I have a website that includes api methods inside. Some actions works for both browser and mobile. Normally when users open the web page they are redirected to login page. But if users come from the mobile they must not be redirected to login page and they will be forced to authenticate via jwt token (bearer)

I just read the .net documentation and found (mixed-dual) authentication thing.

**Here is how i used this feature and waiting for your advise**

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = defaultSetup.CookieExpireTimeSpan;
    options.Cookie.Name = defaultSetup.CookieName;
    options.AccessDeniedPath = identitySettings.ThisProjectAccessDeniedPath;
    options.LoginPath = identitySettings.ThisProjectLoginPath;
    options.LogoutPath = identitySettings.ThisProjectLogoutPath;
})
.AddJwtBearer();
```

**In my Controller**

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = AuthSchemes)]
public class OrderController : BaseController
{
    private const string AuthSchemes =
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme + "," +
        JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
```

If i only use the `[Authorize]` with `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` login page redirection and login works perfect but it always redirects to login page.

If i use the `[Authorize]` with `JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` it works with `Bearer` token only.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have separate Areas for API and Web pages.  You may have controllers with same name in different areas. No doubt, this is repetition of logic, but you may design so that actual implementation is in common methods to be called from two actions.

```
            services.AddAuthentication(options => {
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Console/Account/Index/");
                options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Console/Account/Index/");
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, jwtBearerOptions => {
                jwtBearerOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = JWT_Sec_Key,  
                    ValidateLifetime = true, //validate the expiration and not before values in the token
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5) //5 minute tolerance for the expiration date
                };
            });
```

Here default auth is Cookie, so have only [Authorize] on Web page controllers.

Use [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] for API controllers.

**EDIT:**

I have read it somewhere that you can even provide both schemes like

[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme + "," + CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]

Please give it a try and let me know...

**EDIT2:**
Using multiple annotations is possible. Ref: https://github.com/auth0-samples/aspnet-core-mvc-plus-webapi

[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]

Comment: Did you had a chance to check above... I had also came across https://github.com/auth0-samples/aspnet-core-mvc-plus-webapi, check if it can be any helpful...